# Determine universe of complementary

Tags: complexity-theory

i'm thinking about problems in P complexity, and i have a question:

If a problem "A" is a problem in P, his complementary have to be a problem in P? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every algorithm to decide `A` can be trivially turned into one deciding `not(A)` simply by negating the answer. That doesn't change its complexity.

As you can see from this argument, that's not a special property of the class P. The same argument applies to *all* deterministic complexity classes, hence they are all closed under complement: `DTIME(f(n)) = co-DTIME(f(n))` for all `f`.